# Finding all commands excluding "."

Tags: bash, shell

So far I have this:

```
ls /usr/bin | grep "^[\.]"
```

The cmd still gets files with a "." in there.

I have looked at [[:punct:]] but still returns the same thing.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a file called `/usr/bin/.` and that's the only one you want to exclude? Or do you just want all files without a dot in the name? Do you want to search all files in your path, or just `/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `grep -v` to exclude things. So try

```
ls /usr/bin | grep -v \\.
```

`man grep` says

```
 -v, --invert-match
         Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns.
```

Comment: `.` is a metacharacter that matches anything, so you have to escape it with a backslash for that to work. In the shell, you'll also have to enclose it from quotes, so the final grep call will look like `grep -v "\."`.

Comment: You're right; fixed that. Thanks. I did a quick experiment in my shell and assumed it didn't need escaping, but I misread the experiment.

Comment: Another option would be `grep -vF .` by the way, where `-F` is short for `--fixed-strings`: "Interpret pattern as a set of fixed strings (i.e. force grep to behave as fgrep)."

Answer (score 4):

It's generally considered a [bad idea to parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

If I understand you correctly, you want all files in `/usr/bin` that don't have a dot in the name. You can use `find` to do that:

```
find /usr/bin -not -name "*.*"
```

It is more portable ([thanks @Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475230/finding-all-commands-excluding/25475397?noredirect=1#comment39758920_25475397)) to use a `!` instead of `-not`:

```
find /usr/bin ! -name "*.*"
```

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth thanks, feel free to edit otherwise I'll do so later

Answer (score 2):

Not really clear, what you want:

your command:

```
ls /usr/bin | grep "^[\.]"
```

mean, *filter the output from `ls` to show only files, what are start with a dot*.

```
grep "^[\.]" 
      ^ ^^ - escaped dot
      +- at the begining of the line
```

If you want, exclude all files what contains dot, use

```
ls /usr/bin | grep -v '\.' #or see HenrikN's answer and comments (grep -vF .)
```

it you want exclude only entries what are starting with dot, use

```
grep '^[^\.]'
```

whats mean *anything, but dot at the start*

Ps: anyway, parsing output form `ls` is *usually* an very bad idea. (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Why do you escape the dot in `[]`? Is seems it be unneccessary - http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html (`In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (\), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-).`)

Comment: @skwllsp because it doesn't hurts.. ;) and I have an common behavior, escaping a dot nearly all times.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your regex to exclude files starting with ".":

```
ls -a /usr/bin | grep "^[^.]"
```

This regex selects only files which do not have "." at the start. By the way only `ls -a` shows files that starts with ".". How did you manage to get them without "-a" ?

Comment: Ad: _How did you manage to get them without "-a"_ On some systems, for the user _root_ the `ls` works like `ls -a`.

Comment: I suspect he has an `alias` shell environment that aliases `alias ls='ls -al'` or something similar.

Comment: @jm666 Yes, I also wanted to say it. It must be an alias. Otherwise it is against the spec: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/ls.html

Comment: @skwllsp On the freebsd, the `ls` for the root user shows dotfiles too. (and it isn't an alias) And on the OS X too. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with pure bash, if the `extglob` shell option is enabled.

```
shopt -s extglob
echo /usr/bin/!(*.*)
# or alternatively:
echo /usr/bin/+([!.])
```

You may replace `echo` with `ls -d` if you want to pipe the list to another command line-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the current working directory and parent dirctory and not a command with "a dot" in it.

Try this as you probably have ls aliased:

/bin/ls /usr/bin